# Conditional Statement in ngrx @Effect

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm trying to dispatch one action if my response is successful and a different action if my response is unsuccessful. When I construct the effect like below, I get an invalid action error. Is it possible to add a conditional statement inside an effect?

```
@Effect()
public makeFirstRequest = this.actions.pipe(
    ofType<InitialAction>(ActionTypes.InitialAction),
    switchMap(action => this.myService.firstRequest(action.param)),
    map(response => { 
      if (success) {
        new FollowUpAction(response))
      }else {
        new ErrorAction(response))
      }
);
```

Comment: Where is `sucess` coming from? where is it defined?

Comment: See https://medium.com/city-pantry/handling-errors-in-ngrx-effects-a95d918490d9 for a complete explanation on how to archive what you need

Comment: If the request fails, it'll not go through the map, for that you should rather use `catchError`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm not trying catch an error, but the error is one of the response types. So, it is response.success or response.error. In other words, I need to evaluate the response and then based on the response value dispatch one of two actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the action:

```
map(response => { 
      if (success) {
        return new FollowUpAction(response)
      }else {
        return  new ErrorAction(response)
      }
});
```

Comment: So simple. Thanks!

Comment: Can multiple actions be returned? I'm getting a similar error when I do this:

`if (success) {
    return [
      new FollowupAction1(response),
      new FollowupAction2(response)
   ]}else {}'

Comment: As a solution, I used one action for the "success" return which initiated another action that had both followup actions. I don't know if this is the best solution but it worked.